# dnsutils deprecated, ldns has drill command but no short option

Tags: bash, dns, ip, arch-linux, dig

The dig command is deprecated. I'm using drill from ldns. Drill doesn't seem to have a short option to show only the ip. Does anyone know how I can make it show only the ip and not the other text.

Comment: May I ask where did you read that `dig` is deprecated? I missed that news. Is it a joke?

Comment: https://www.archlinux.org/todo/dnsutils-to-ldns-migration/

Comment: You know you can still have `dig` with the `bind-tools` package (https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/bind-tools/) right ?

Answer (score 0):

[Found a way to do it with curl and cloudflare](https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/24675/ultra-fast-public-ip-address-lookup-using-cloudflares-1.1.1.1)

```
curl -fSs https://1.1.1.1/cdn-cgi/trace | awk -F= '/ip/ { print $2 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

`dig` with`+short` look like this:

```
$ dig +short example.com
XXX.XX.XX.XXX
```

So, you could simply do:

```
$ drill example.com | awk '{if(NF > 0 && substr($1,1,1) != ";") print $NF }'
XXX.XX.XX.XXX
```

## Understanding my `awk`

```
if (NF > 0)  # If the line is not empty
if (substr($1,1,1) != ";") # If the first character is not `;`
print $NF # Print the last column.
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late the party here, but it looks like `drill` ~now~ has a `-Q` ("quiet") flag that does the same as dig's `+short`:

```
$ drill -Q superuser.com
104.18.8.56
104.18.9.56
```

**UPDATE**: Looks like the feature has been in `ldns` since [at least the 1.0.0 release](https://github.com/NLnetLabs/ldns/blob/release-1.0.0/drill/drill.c#L29). You probably just missed it in your research because `drill` doesn't aim to be a 100% drop-in replacement for `dig`?

---

**Previous Answer**

> What's a little surprising is, that feature was apparently [committed in 2005](https://github.com/NLnetLabs/ldns/commit/bc98c1b84c771300a672201c1e5f130d9dc50a47#diff-98b9bc6ac07b63f786a3db1df3e1b24d156d9fbfa7be5cd340f1517d31e858b5R8), but not in a released version [until Nov 2021](https://github.com/NLnetLabs/ldns/releases/tag/1.8.0-rc.1).
>
> I'm not sure what caused it (and other commits) to sit in limbo for 16 years, but at least you have a `drill`-native solution now!